# Android php service connection on apache 2.2 - index.php not respond after some successfull connections

Tags: php, android, apache, database-connection

I started to develope an android application which is going to use a database connection over a php service.

I successfully installed apache 2.2 server and php 5 and configured them.
There is no connection problem in my project but the problem is:
1) Application connects to the php service, executes query and takes result,
2) But after some query runnings, service starts not to respond and i just couldn't resolve it during 2 days.

When the service starts not to respond, i check it from the explorer by typing in http:/localhost:8888/android_api/ (android_api is the folder which contains the php service functions) and result appears as no response. When i refresh the page it starts to respond again.

my php code (index.php at localhost:8888/android_api) :

```
<?php
/**
 * File to handle all API requests
 * Accepts GET and POST
 *
 * Each request will be identified by TAG
 * Response will be JSON data

/**
 * check for POST request
 */
if (isset($_POST['tag']) && $_POST['tag'] != '') {
    // get tag
    $tag = $_POST['tag'];

    // include db handler
    require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
    $db = new DB_Functions();

    // response Array
    $response = array("tag" => $tag, "success" => 0, "error" => 0);

    // check for tag type
    if ($tag == 'insert') {
        // Request type is check Login
        $icao = $_POST['icao'];
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $latitude = $_POST['latitude'];
        $longitude = $_POST['longitude'];

        // check for user
        $result = $db->insertAirport($icao, $name, $latitude, $longitude);
        if ($result) {
            $response["success"] = 1;
        } else {
            $response["error"] = 1;
        }
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else if ($tag == 'getall') {
        $result = $db->getAllAirports();
        $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if($no_of_rows > 0) {
            $response["success"] = 1;
            while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $response[$result["icao"]] = $r;
            }
        } else {
            $response["error"] = 1;
        }
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        echo "Invalid Request";
    }
} else {
    echo "Access Denied";
}
?>
```

android code where the connection is processed :

```
 try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The url and params variables contain correct data. Any help will be godlike.

Comment: Anyway the error has just disappeared and the service is running flawless now. The error was about anything except android and php server or it was a bug i guess.